# Bootstrapping Gcloud Cloud SQL 2nd Gen instance

Tags: command-line, scripting, google-cloud-sql, gcloud

My Bootstrapping effort for creating Cloud SQL 2nd gen instances went smoothly apart from one thing.

it refused to accept the parameter for MYSQL_5_7.

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud sql instances create ops-sql-2 --activation-policy=ALWAYS --backup --tier=db-n1-standard-2 --region=europe-west1 --gce-zone=europe-west1-b --database-version=mysql_5_7 --require-ssl  --assign-ip --backup-start-time=02:00
usage: gcloud sql instances create  INSTANCE [optional flags]
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.create) argument --database-version: Invalid choice: 'mysql_5_7'.

Valid choices are [MYSQL_5_5, MYSQL_5_6, MYSQL_5_7, POSTGRES_9_5].

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud sql instances create ops-sql- 2 --activation-policy=ALWAYS --backup --tier=db-n1-standard-2 --region=europe-west1 --gce-zone=europe-west1-b --database-version MYSQL_5_7 --require-ssl  --assign-ip --backup-start-time=02:00
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.create) Invalid value for: MYSQL_5_7 is not a valid value:
```

is this a bug or am I missing something weird ?    If it is a bug is there a method to get these sorted ASAP as I dont want to install MYSQL_5_6 which works fine in this script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try "gcloud beta sql instances" instead of "gcloud sql instances"?

gcloud beta usually has the newest features/options: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/

Comment: this worked for me. Got an error "May not assign arbitrary value enabled to message IpConfiguration" at first but think that was related to one of the newer switches, when I stripped it back it to a more basic command, the db version worked.

Comment: It's probably the --assign-ip option. Second Gen instances always have an ipv4 address so that option is not necessary. (It's a bug that it didn't print a nicer error message.)

Comment: They have now released the latest version of gloud and still the beta flag exists.  There is also a couple of settings such as maintenance window that don't appear to be possible in gcloud..   don't think the command line scripting tool should lag behind the UI